# VS Code error: "The .NET Core SDK cannot be located"

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner.

I'm using MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020), and I had installed programs including Unity, VS code, .NET 6.0 SDK x64 & arm64 (I have searched but I didn't know what to choose. So I had both of them) and .NET 5.0.203 SDK (tried after watching someone's blog).

Then it keeps saying "The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path." on VS Code.

What can I try to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this Link to find out which Processor you got:
https://appletoolbox.com/intel-or-arm/

If you have an M1, you should have an ARM. So deinstall the SDK Version for Intel and reinstall the ARM Version.

If you have still a failure, please describe the failure more (i.e. When did the failure occur? While starting VS Code?).